# Finding the first,last,and middle value in an array. Return the largest one

Tags: java

Java newbie is here. I'm practicing the array question, and I had problem with this question: Given an array of ints of odd length, look at the first, last, and middle values in the array and return the largest. The array length will be a least 1.

I know how to find the first,last,and middle value in an array. Then I tried to use if statement to solve this question.

My code:

```
public int maxTriple(int[] nums) {
    if(nums[0]>nums[(nums.length+1)/2-1]&&nums[0]>nums[nums.length-1]){
       return nums[0];
   }else if(nums[(nums.length+1)/2-1>]>nums[0]&&nums[(nums.length+1)/2-1>]>
            nums[nums.length-1]){
       return nums[nums.length-1];
   }else{
       return nums[nums.length-1];
 }
}
```

But this code does not work at all how can I fix my code?

Comment: Start by looking at the compilation errors and fixing them, then take it from there...

Comment: Are you aware that you return `nums[nums.length-1]` **twice**?

Comment: @PM77-1 Sorry I was typing wrong my original one should be `return nums[(nums.length+1)/2-1];`

Comment: Please fix the code in your question, not as a comment. Could you post [mcve] ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, to make the code more readable/understandable, you should assign the 3 values of interest to local variables, and you should add some spaces around operators.

Also, since you *know* the length will be odd, `length / 2` is enough to find middle value:

```
int first  = nums[0];
int middle = nums[nums.length / 2];
int last   = nums[nums.length - 1];
```

When your `if` block ends with a `return` statement, the `else` becomes redundant, though that is a matter of style. In this case it makes little difference, but in more complex code it can make a big difference to the code complexity.

And of course, your main problem, as [PM 77-1 pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43421641/finding-the-first-last-and-middle-value-in-an-array-return-the-largest-one#comment73902208_43421641).

> Are you aware that you return `nums[nums.length-1]` **twice**?

The middle `return` statement was returning the wrong value:

```
if (first > middle && first > last) {
    return first;
}
if (middle > first && middle > last) {
    return middle;
}
return last;
```

You can use the ternary conditional operator to write that in a single statement:

```
return (first > middle && first > last ? first :
        middle > first && middle > last ? middle : last);
```

You can use the [`Math.max()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#max-int-int-) method to simplify it:

```
return Math.max(Math.max(first, middle), last);
```

Or you can use [`IntStream.max()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#max--), which is better if you have many values:

```
return IntStream.of(first, middle, last).max().getAsInt();
```

Comment: Thanks for you very details answer! But in terms of finding middle value of odd length array should I use`nums[(nums.length+1)/2-1]`? Since I make the array length even.

Comment: @KanzakiAriaEcho You said: *"Given an array of ints of **odd length**"*. Since length is odd, e.g. `9`, dividing by `2` results in `4` (truncated), which *is* the index of the middle element of a size 9 array. Question makes little sense for even-sized array, since there is no *single* "middle" element in such an array.

Answer (score 1):

In second else-if you have extra ">" (maybe it is a misspelling)

And if the second condition is true you need to return `nums[(nums.length+1)/2-1`

So you need to fix it in this way:

```
public int maxTriple(int[] nums) {
        if(nums[0]>nums[(nums.length+1)/2-1]&&nums[0]>nums[nums.length-1]){
            return nums[0];
        }else if(nums[(nums.length+1)/2-1]>nums[0]&&nums[(nums.length+1)/2-1]>nums[nums.length-1]){
            return nums[(nums.length+1)/2-1];
        }else{
            return nums[nums.length-1];
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are only interest in the value, not the index, you can use

```
public int maxTriple(int[] nums) {
   int max = Math.max(nums[0], nums[nums.length - 1]);
   return Math.max(max, nums[nums.length / 2]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Readable more than multiple conditions :

```
public int maxTriple(int[] nums) {
    return Math.max(Math.max(nums[0], nums[nums.length - 1]), nums[nums.length / 2]);
}
```